# Can't able to get reference of third Party framework in my custom framework

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch

I am making my custom Cocoa Touch Framework in which I want to import third-party framework.

I have added the framework in `Targets > Linked Frameworks and Libraries`

And making reference in my `.swift` file. But its showing error(Use of unresolved identifier)

Can anyone guide me: The proper procedure to use a third-party framework in my custom framework.